# Tornado's equivalent to native socket's recv() method

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

So, I've started using **Tornado** for my asynchronous socket server and everything looked fine, until I've discovered a strange `read_bytes(num_bytes)` method.

Because I have to read UTF from Java's `OutputStream`, I had to re-write a "parser" in Python and that's how a code looks like right now:

```
def read_utf(self, callback):
    def _utf_length(data):
        self.stream.read_bytes(data, _read_utf)
    def _read_utf(data):
        callback(struct.unpack('>H', data)[0])
    self.stream.read_bytes(2, _utf_length)
```

But.. It doesn't work. That's how a traceback looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 600, in _run_callback
ret = callback()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 554, in wrapper
return callback(*args)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "..\streams.py", line 57, in _utf_length
self.stream.read_bytes(data, _read_utf)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 312, in read_bytes
assert isinstance(num_bytes, numbers.Integral)
AssertionError
```

I tried to use `self.stream.read_bytes(int(data), _read_utf)`, but that didn't worked because string is "empty" itself.

**What can I do at this point?**

Comment: Use a number as your first argument for read_bytes? What's the problem.

Comment: *cough* Have you read my question properly?

Comment: Yes, but it was very vague. If you want more help then you have to at the very least tell us what `data` is

Comment: `type(data)` returns a `str` object, so..

Comment: and read_bytes takes a number, so you can't use data as an argument. What's the problem

Comment: I can't even parse `data` it into an `int`, because the string is empty. I need to do that because of strange UTF format in Java where I have to read first 2 bytes in order to get a size of a string and read it whole.

Comment: How many bytes do you expect read_bytes to read then?

Comment: I can't expect *anything*: these numbers are pretty much unpredictable because I'm not a super hero and I'm not able to know what string I'm gonna get up next.

Comment: `if data != "": ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use struct.unpack on the data you receive in `_utf_length`. `_read_utf` gets the real data which you want to pass to your own callback:

```
def read_utf(self, callback):
    def _utf_length(data):
        length = struct.unpack('>H', data)[0]
        self.stream.read_bytes(length, _read_utf)
    def _read_utf(data):
        callback(data)
    self.stream.read_bytes(2, _utf_length)
```

Also consider writing this as a coroutine; it can be easier to follow than a series of callbacks:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def read_utf(self):
    length_data = yield self.stream.read_bytes(2)
    length = struct.unpack('>H', length_data)[0]
    data = yield self.stream.read_bytes(length)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(data)
```